# Can a likert score questionnaire be programmed with mathematica?

Tags: plotting, graphics

I am a phD student and as part of my investigation I will be applying a Likert style questionnaire. The answers give will pick from a scale 1 to 5. Can I program the questionnaire, text, and the 1 to 5 selections in matemática, then have the personnel take the questionnaire from their computer? Matemática runs in the back end and I can see as questions get answered not just the final result but also the dynamics of the answers as logged?

Comment: Would the people you are giving this to have Mathematica installed on their computers? If not, they would not be able to fill out and submit the answers.

Perhaps a better idea is to make a Deployed webform with a Databin and distribute it via the wolframcloud? https://www.wolframcloud.com/

Comment: Here is an example: https://blog.wolfram.com/2017/06/22/create-a-tracker-to-analyze-gas-mileage-using-wolfram-tech/

Comment: Thank you for both replies. I found a tutorial in the documentation center about databins, but the milage example from FredrikD is extra-excellent. I will get to work..!